# MATLAB Coding difficulty. Summation notation coding in matlab

Tags: matlab, math, encoding

If the all entities `QT` are variables then

1. How to define variables QT such that they automatically get defined for given values of n, k, j, ...etc.
2. How to code this summation notation in matlab ?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking Im afraid.

Comment: What i am actually trying to do is to solve a large scale Linear programming problem. So it contains a large set of variables which are written in this summation notation. I want to code such a program that i have to input only the index values like n,k,l,m,etc & the required parameters in matrix or scaler form and using the solver i can solve/ optimize the problem. In doing so these two problems are arising 1) define variables automatically for values of n,m,k,l   2) how to use those variables instead of defining each constraint separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your QT as a 3D array.

Having different subscripts doesn't matter on the left hand side hence that's just 2 times the sum of the `QT_{nk}` in the 3rd dimension. Hence

```
2*sum(QT,3)
```

gives you the left hand side. Right hand side is a bit trickier but same idea holds. This time you are summing in the second dimension and then multiplying with the row index. Hence right hand side is

```
sum(QT,2)*diag([a1,...,an])
```

But this is an equation so I don't know if you are trying to solve these symbolically or solve for `a` etc. which is another story.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What i am actually trying to do is to solve a large scale Linear programming problem. So it contains a large set of variables which are written in this summation notation. I want to code such a program that i have to input only the index values like n,k,l,m,etc & the required parameters in matrix or scaler form and using the solver i can solve/ optimize the problem.